# Dead simple example of synaptic js lstm rnn algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, machine-learning

It's pretty crazy that there isn't a *dead simple* example of the LSTM RNN predicting time series data.

https://github.com/cazala/synaptic

https://github.com/cazala/synaptic/wiki/Architect#lstm

I'd like to use the historical data in the following array:

```
const array = [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1
];
```

Some pretty mind blowing data right there right?

I'd like to A) train the algorithm with the array then B) test the algorithm with the following array:

```
const array = [
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    0
];
```

Should result in it predicting a `0`.

Unfortunately the documentation is pretty bad, no clear code examples exist. Anyone have any examples?

Comment: Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43589015/lstm-figuring-out-the-library?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11):

This answer is not written with Synaptic, but with [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic). I decided to make a quick answer that I will include in the documentation soon. This is the code, it works 9/10 times:

```
var network = new neataptic.architect.LSTM(1,6,1);

// when the timeseries is [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1...]
var trainingData = [
  { input: [0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0], output: [1] },
  { input: [1], output: [0] },
  { input: [0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0], output: [1] },
];

network.train(trainingData, {
  log: 500,
  iterations: 6000,
  error: 0.03,
  clear: true,
  rate: 0.05,
});
```

[Run it on JSFIDDLE to see the prediction!](https://jsfiddle.net/9t2787k5/3/) For more predictions, open [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/9t2787k5/4/).

Explanation to some choices I made:

- I set option **clear** to true, as you want do a chronological timeseries prediction. This makes sure that the network starts from the 'beginning' every training iteration, instead of continuing on from the 'end' of the last iteration.
- Rate is fairly low, higher rates will get stuck at an MSE error of `~0.2`
- The LSTM has 1 block of 6 memory nodes, lower amounts don't seem to work as well.

Comment: can you explain a little more what input/output is? Is input the first number of the time series and output the second number of the time series? ie: if my time series is: [0.2, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2] would I then input 0.2 and output 0.4 for the first line? and then for the second line, input: 0.4 and output: 0.1?

Comment: Yes exactly, i'll update my answer to be more clear.

Comment: Heads up, latest version `new neataptic.architect.LSTM(1,6,1);`,  notice the `A` & `a`.